# Determine all subspaces $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\phi (U)=U$.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, invariant-subspace

We have the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ and let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, \ x\mapsto Ax$ be the endomorphism to $A$.

I have found the eigenvalues which are $1,2,-1$. Since we have three dinstinct eigenvalues it follows that $A$ and so also $\phi$ is diagonalizable.

Is that correct?

Then for each eigenvalue I calculated the eigenspaces. The set of the three eigenvectors forms a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, right?

I want to determine all subspaces $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\phi (U)=U$.

How can we do that? Is this maybe related to the eigenvectors?

Comment: To start with, consider the spaces spanned by (some of) the eigenvectors. That is, if $B = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is an eigenbasis, consider the $8$ subspaces you get by considering the span of the $8$ different subsets of $B$.

Comment: Also, you are correct about $A$ (and $\phi$) being diagonalisable as well as fact that those three eigenvectors will form a basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did is fine. And now, if $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_{-1}$ are eigenvalues corresponding to the eigenvalues $1$, $2$, and $-1$ respectively, then the subspaces $U$ of $\Bbb R^3$ such that $\phi(U)=U$ are:

- $\{0\}$;
- $\Bbb Rv_1$;
- $\Bbb Rv_2$;
- $\Bbb Rv_{-1}$;
- $\Bbb Rv_1\bigoplus\Bbb Rv_{-1}$;
- $\Bbb Rv_1\bigoplus\Bbb Rv_2$;
- $\Bbb Rv_{-1}\bigoplus\Bbb Rv_2$;
- $\Bbb R^3$.

It is clear that each of these spaces is invariant. On the other hand, let $U\subset\Bbb R^3$ be such that $\phi(U)\subset U$. If $\dim U$ is $0$, $1$ or $3$, it's clear that $U$ belongs to the list from above. If $\dim U=2$, let $\psi\colon U\longrightarrow U$ be the restriction of $\phi$ to $U$. So, $\psi$ has $2$ complex eigenvalues, which must be a subset of $\{1,2,-1\}$. But then $U$ has to be one of the $3$ $2$-dimensional spaces from above.

Comment: It is clear that these are invariant. How would one show that these are all?

Comment: @hello I've added more details to my answer.

Comment: This is true if $\psi$ has two different eigenvalues. But it is possible that $\psi$ has only one eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity $2$, in this case $U$ cannot be one of the above subspaces

Comment: @Student Not possible. If $\lambda$ was a double eigenvalue of $\psi$, then two linearly independent vectors $w_1$ and $w_2$ of $U$ would have eigenvalue $\lambda$. But $w_1$ and $w_2$ would also be linearly independent vectors of $\Bbb R^3$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ with respect to $\phi$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ equals $2$ doesn't mean that the dimension of its eigenspace is 2, it means that $\lambda$ is a root of order $2$ of the characteristic polynomial of $\psi$

Comment: @Student Right. My bad. But you can use the fact that [the characteristic polynomial of $\psi$ must divide the characteristic polynomial of $\phi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2662196/446262).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You are right, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Does $\Bbb Rv_1\bigoplus\Bbb Rv_{-1}$ mean the set that consists of the eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_{-1}$ ?

Comment: We consider all possible combinations of eigenvectors because of the property $\phi (v)=\lambda v$, right?

Comment: If $\text{dim}(U)=\{0,1,3\}$ why are the only possible subspaces the one listed above? Ihaven't rally understood the partwith $\psi$. Why do we have totake a restriction of $\phi$. Could you explain that futher to me?

Comment: The space $\Bbb Rv_1\bigoplus\Bbb Rv_2$ is the span of $\{v_1,v_2\}$, that is, it's the space of all linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: The only $0$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ is $\{0\}$, which is invariant. The only $3$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ is $\Bbb R^3$, which is also invariant. And if a $1$-dimensional subspace $U$ of $\Bbb R^3$ is invariant, then $U=\Bbb Rv$ for some vector $v\ne0$ and, since $\phi(U)\subset U$, $\phi(v)=\lambda v$ for some scalar $\lambda$. So, $v$ is an eigenvector of $\phi$.

Comment: And I never claimed that we **have** to take the restriction of $\phi$ to $U$. It turns out that that's how I solved the problem.

Comment: Could you explain to me further to part when $U$ is $2$-dimensional?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127419/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-mary-star).